# how to echo object or hash type field php

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, get, echo

Please how do I echo or obtain the values of a field of type object?
I first encoded, replaced string and decoded the code as below:

```
$mongorow = json_encode($mongorow);

$mongorow= preg_replace("/_DOT_/",  ".", $mongorow);

$mongorow = json_decode($mongorow);
```

And then in my form I'm trying to use the fields as below:

```
value="<?php echo $mongorow->name;?>" //this works producing value of name
value="<?php echo $mongorow->properties;?>"  //this produces an error where properties is of type object
```

Error message I get is (symfony)

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in ...

Comment: Show us the output of `var_dump($mongorow)`.

Comment: I assume object `$mongorow` contains another object `properties`. And thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

First try to debug the type of the `$mongorow->properties` you can debug the object by using the var_dumb function.

Try this:

```
var_dump($mongorow);
```

And you will get the exact data.

[For more read here about the var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump).

Answer (score 1):

You can use var_dump() or print_r() function to display the object or hashtype field

```
 echo "<pre>"; var_dump($mongorow); 

 print_r($mongorow);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign object to the variable as a string use:

```
serialize($obj);
```

If you want to just dump value on screen use:

```
var_dump($obj);`
```